# How to disable one query in Postgres for specified (partioned) table

Tags: postgresql, table-plus

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM "public"."views";
```

This query executes every time by TablePlus client when I open a partitioned table with many partitions and processed too long time.

How I can disable the execution of this query on this table?

Comment: you should ask [their support](https://tableplus.io/contact)

Comment: You can revoke permissions to SELECT from this table for your client. But this will probably break your TablePlus software. It's better to ask it not to execute this query in first place.

Comment: The application has to be fixed. [Here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/count-made-fast/) are some pointers how.